# Bad local forwarding specification while connecting to cluster

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, jupyter

I am connecting to a data cluster and following these steps:

(I obviously have my .ssh/config file set up properly)

1. Open the tunnel
2. SSH into the cluster
3. Try to bind a port to the server so I can use a Jupyter notebook through this command: `ssh -N -L 22127:localhost:22127 [cluster_name]`
4. Run the ipython command on the cluster through: `ipython notebook --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=22127 --no-browser`

In the end, on step 3, I always get a "Bad local forwarding error". Please note that I have people next to me who have the exact same commands and configurations on the .ssh/config file and can connect and run the Jupyter server.

Comment: What is the complete error message that you get at step 3? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Kenster is it exactly `Bad local forwarding specification '22127:localhost:22127 [cluster_name]' `

Comment: I encountered this `Bad local forwarding specification` error and then solved it. The reason is some character in the command was of wrong encoding. In my case it was a blank space `\xc2\xa0`. Hope this comment could shine some light of somebody else who also encounters the same problem.

Comment: @PL-RL the ` [cluster_name]` should not be appearing in the error message. This suggests that the space between `22127` and `[cluster_name]` is some non-breakeable space that your terminal does not recognize, thus everything is considered one argument. If you copied the command from somewhere, try writing it out yourself

Answer (score 7):

Those both are UTF-8 encoded spaces.

```
\xc2\xa0
\x0a\x20
```

Make sure you use second one.

Comment: My EXACT ISSUE -- i was pasting in a command, had a weird CHAR. Typed it out manually -- all fine!